# How to crawl and scrape data at the same time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

It's my first experience with web scraping and I'm not sure if I'm doing well or not. The thing is I want to crawl and scrape data at the same time.

- Get all the links that I'm gonna scrape
- Store them into MongoDB
- Visit them one by one to scrape their content

  ```
  # Crawling: get all links to be scrapped later on 
  class LinkCrawler(Spider):
      name="link"
      allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
      start_urls = ["https://www.website.com/offres?start=%s" % start for start in xrange(0,10000,20)]
      def parse(self,response):
          # loop for all pages
          next_page = Selector(response).xpath('//li[@class="active"]/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href').extract()

          if not not next_page:
              yield Request("https://"+next_page[0], callback = self.parse)

          # loop for all links in a single page
          links = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="row-fluid job-details pointer"]/div[@class="bloc-right"]/div[@class="row-fluid"]')

          for link in links:
              item = Link()
              url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract())
              item['url'] = url
              items.append(item)

          for item in items:
              yield item

  # Scraping: get all the stored links on MongoDB and scrape them????
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your use case? Are you primarily interested in the links or content of the pages they lead to? I.e. is there any reason to first store the links in MongoDB and scrape pages later? If you really need to store links in MongoDB, it's best to use an [item pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) to store the items. In the link, there's even example of storing items in MongoDB. If you need something more sophisticated, look at [scrapy-mongodb](https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb) package.

Other than that, there are some comments to the actual code you posted:

- Instead of `Selector(response).xpath(...)` use just `response.xpath(...)`.
- If you need only the first extracted element from selector, use `extract_first()` instead of using `extract()` and indexing.
- Don't use `if not not next_page:`, use `if next_page:`.
- The second loop over `items` is not needed, `yield` item in the loop over `links`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. The site I'm scraping is e-commerce site where people sell items and once sold they remove them. So in order for me to know which products were sold to fast I think I have to keep storing links to check later if they where removed or not. Also if it possible to scrape the content of every link before storing that link on mongodb, show me how can I do that please?

Comment: If links to individual products follow some common pattern, it's probably better to use [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) with appropriate rules.

Comment: Yes to individual products, but is there a tuto out there? I wanna visit every link and extract the data exposed in there ...

Comment: @geek-tech I provided you with the link above, there's an example. Did you look at it?

Comment: Oh sorry, will have a look and get back if needed ... thanks :)